# Proof that the set of all functions $f : \mathbb{Z}^{+} \rightarrow \{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 \}$ is uncountable

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let

$ A= \{ f \vert f: \mathbb{Z}^{+} \rightarrow \{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 \} \}$.

Now, if we want to prove that it is uncountable, we can prove that there doesn't exist a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $A$.

Let's assume that there exists a bijection $\Phi : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A, n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $ \Phi(n) \rightarrow f_n$, so that among $f_n$, exist all functions in $A$. Let's define a function

$g : \mathbb{Z}^{+} \rightarrow \{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 \} $ in the following way:

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & f(x)=1 \\
1, & f(x)=2 \\
2, & f(x)=1 \\
...
\end{cases}$$

for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$

I didn't go all the way from $0$ to $9$ because either way I think it's sufficient to show that at least one value is different.

It's evident that such a function $g(x)$ can't be contained among the functions $f_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ since its value is different from all values of $f_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ for at least one $n$.

**My question is:** Is this a valid proof? I saw a similar approach to showing that the set of all functions from R to R has a bigger cardinality than $c$, and I used an analogous approach but I'm so far not convinced that this is correct.

Comment: You can show the {0, 1}-valued functions on the positive integers are uncountable via an off-the-shelf diagonal argument.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how $g$ is defined, and why there is some value such that $g(m) \neq f_n (m)$?

Comment: $g$ needs to be defined using $f_x(x)$, not $f(x)$. $f_x$ are the specific functions in your assumed sequence $\Phi$. $f$ is just some arbitrary function.